# Have a layout that overlaps the actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, overlapping

I am creating an instructions screen in android, (similar to the screen that android makes when you turn on your smartphone for the first time.) I need to make a layout that overlaps the entire screen (content and `ActionBar`). How do I do that.

- Which layout do I use
- How do I overlap it above the action bar?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the link to the image:

[image: Android Instructions Screen]

I'd like to make something like this. Thus I need to have a layout that overlaps the whole screen. (Except that notification bar at the very top)

Answer (score 0):

```
       You can use Alert box for this when you enter in that screen then first it call this code after that rest of your screen code what ever you write in your activity here is my code 

         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainCleanerActivity.this);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("YOUR TITLE");
                        alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("YOUR APP MESSAGE WHICH YOU WANT TO SHOW
")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                              });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Sorry. But I need it to be a tutorial type screen. Not just a regualar alert box

Comment: then make custom alert box dear and you now you can make all activity as a alertbox type use that one \

Comment: really? Can you link me to a place that will teach me how to do that?